# boost::any_cast - throw only when an implicit conversion isn't available?

Tags: c++, boost

I want `boost::any_cast<T>` to only throw an exception when the type of the `any` doesn't have an implicit conversion to `T`. The normal behaviour seems to be to throw an exception if the type of the `any` is not `T`, regardless of implicit conversions.

Example:

```
boost::any a = 1;
boost::any_cast<int>(a); // This succeeds, and rightfully so
boost::any_cast<long>(a); // I don't want this to throw
boost::any_cast<Widget>(a); // I want this to throw
```

Could anyone tell me if there's a simple way to get the functionality I want, or better yet give me a good reason for why the existing behaviour is the way it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can't do it. The `any` mechanism works like this:

```
struct base {
    virtual ~base() { }
};

template<typename T>
struct concrete_base : base {
    T t;
    concrete_base(T t):t(t) { }
};

struct my_any {
    base * b;

    template<typename T>
    my_any(T t):b(new concrete_base<T>(t)) { }

    template<typename T>
    T any_cast() { 
        concrete_base<T> * t = dynamic_cast< concrete_base<T>* >(b);
        if(!t) throw bad_any_cast();
        return t->t;
    }
};
```

I hope it's clear what the above does. There is no way you could do what you are looking for i think. The reason is that there is no information about the type kept that could prove useful here. RTTI doesn't provide it.

Answer (score -1):

any_cast can't do it but if the base and derived types are complete (which they usually are for types that are in a hierarchy) you could implement your own system which converts by means of throw and catch, since throwing a pointer to a derived type can be caught as a base pointer type.

Comment: `throw` and `catch` are for handling errors, not stumbling around deliberate restrictions in someone else's interface. (I don't know enough to say whether they're even necessary/useful here, but I know this idea/advice is bad in any case.) If someone wants a type-erasing container with implicit conversion, then they should write their own.